# Equivalence of Vertices

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, equivalence-relations

A directed graph D is strongly connected if and only if each vertex
pair is equivalent. Show that this is indeed an equivalence relation on the vertex set of D and that each equivalence class (which is a vertex set of D) induces a subgraph of D which is strongly connected.

It is not clear form me about What do we mean by the equivalence of vertices of G? any help

Comment: It might help us understand the problem if you told us what book you copied that problem from.

Comment: Rather, I expect that reading the previous paragraph or two of that book will answer the question.